# How to drag and drop item from one list to another without it remove from first list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a list that in the first list items should be fixed and then on the second list, you should able to drag and drop the first item list and you should able to rearrange them.

I found a [useful link](http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable) and I created my code. My problem is that when I am drag and drop from the first list to second list the item will remove from the first list.

Since I am new in Javascript, I am seeking your help in how to disable disappearing the item from list 1 or regenerate it as shown in the picture.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

my HTML file:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HTML5 Sortable jQuery Plugin</title>
    <style>
        header, section {
            display: block;
        }
        body {
            font-family: 'Droid Serif';
        }
        h1, h2 {
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: normal;
        }
        #features {
            margin: auto;
            width: 460px;
            font-size: 0.9em;
        }
        .connected, .sortable, .exclude, .handles {
            margin: auto;
            padding: 0;
            width: 310px;
            -webkit-touch-callout: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }
        .sortable.grid {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .connected li, .sortable li, .exclude li, .handles li {
            list-style: none;
            border: 1px solid #CCC;
            background: #F6F6F6;
            font-family: "Tahoma";
            color: #1C94C4;
            margin: 5px;
            padding: 5px;
            height: 22px;
        }
        .handles span {
            cursor: move;
        }
        li.disabled {
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
        .sortable.grid li {
            line-height: 80px;
            float: left;
            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        li.highlight {
            background: #FEE25F;
        }
        #connected {
            width: 440px;
            overflow: hidden;
            margin: auto;
        }
        .connected {
            float: left;
            width: 200px;
        }
        .connected.no2 {
            float: right;
        }
        li.sortable-placeholder {
            border: 1px dashed #CCC;
            background: none;
        }
    </style>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>HTML5 Sortable jQuery Plugin</h1>
    </header>
    <section id="connected" >
        <h2>Connected Sortable Lists</h2>
        <ul class="connected list" >
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li >Item 2</li>
            <li >Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
            <li>Item 5</li>
            <li >Item 6</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="connected list no2">
            <li class="highlight">Item 1</li>
            <li class="highlight">Item 2</li>
            <li class="highlight">Item 3</li>
            <li class="highlight">Item 4</li>
            <li class="highlight">Item 5</li>
            <li class="highlight">Item 6</li>
        </ul>
    </section>
    <a href="http://github.com/farhadi/html5sortable"><img style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; border: 0;" src="https://a248.e.akamai.net/assets.github.com/img/edc6dae7a1079163caf7f17c60495bbb6d027c93/687474703a2f2f73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f6769746875622f726962626f6e732f666f726b6d655f6c6566745f677265656e5f3030373230302e706e67" alt="Fork me on GitHub"></a>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.sortable.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('.connected').sortable({
                connectWith: '.connected'
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript file:

```
/*
 * HTML5 Sortable jQuery Plugin
 * http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable
 * 
 * Copyright 2012, Ali Farhadi
 * Released under the MIT license.
 */
(function($) {
var dragging, placeholders = $();
$.fn.sortable = function(options) {
    var method = String(options);
    options = $.extend({
        connectWith: false
    }, options);
    return this.each(function() {
        if (/^enable|disable|destroy$/.test(method)) {
            var items = $(this).children($(this).data('items')).attr('draggable', method == 'enable');
            if (method == 'destroy') {
                items.add(this).removeData('connectWith items')
                    .off('dragstart.h5s dragend.h5s selectstart.h5s dragover.h5s dragenter.h5s drop.h5s');
            }
            return;
        }

        var isHandle, index, items = $(this).children(options.items);
        var placeholder = $('<' + (/^ul|ol$/i.test(this.tagName) ? 'li' : 'div') + ' class="sortable-placeholder">');
        items.find(options.handle).mousedown(function() {
            isHandle = true;
        }).mouseup(function() {
            isHandle = false;
        });
        $(this).data('items', options.items)
        placeholders = placeholders.add(placeholder);
        if (options.connectWith) {
            $(options.connectWith).add(this).data('connectWith', options.connectWith);
        }
        items.attr('draggable', 'true').on('dragstart.h5s', function(e) {
            if (options.handle && !isHandle) {
                return false;
            }
            isHandle = false;
            var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
            dt.effectAllowed = 'move';
            dt.setData('Text', 'dummy');
            index = (dragging = $(this)).addClass('sortable-dragging').index();
        }).on('dragend.h5s', function() {
            dragging.removeClass('sortable-dragging').show();
            placeholders.detach();
            if (index != dragging.index()) {
                items.parent().trigger('sortupdate', {item: dragging});
            }
            dragging = null;
        }).not('a[href], img').on('selectstart.h5s', function() {
            this.dragDrop && this.dragDrop();
            return false;
        }).end().add([this, placeholder]).on('dragover.h5s dragenter.h5s drop.h5s', function(e) {
            if (!items.is(dragging) && options.connectWith !== $(dragging).parent().data('connectWith')) {
                return true;
            }
            if (e.type == 'drop') {
                e.stopPropagation();
                placeholders.filter(':visible').after(dragging);
                return false;
            }
            e.preventDefault();
            e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
            if (items.is(this)) {
                if (options.forcePlaceholderSize) {
                    placeholder.height(dragging.outerHeight());
                }
                dragging.hide();
                $(this)[placeholder.index() < $(this).index() ? 'after' : 'before'](placeholder);
                placeholders.not(placeholder).detach();
            } else if (!placeholders.is(this) && !$(this).children(options.items).length) {
                placeholders.detach();
                $(this).append(placeholder);
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I would be happy to help if you want to produce your own code.  But in the mean time, in your search, you may want to look at 'clone' or 'copy'.  Drag-and-drop implies a 'move' operation - which is usually defined something like - make copy, do something with copy, upon completion destroy original.

Comment: @terary: Yes I would like to write my own code, but my problem is I don't like Jquery. after 4 hours breaking my head I prefer to use some expert help. It is kind of emergency. plz, help.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: the final code should be able to run in node.js

Comment: @Amir this is client-side code, intended to be run on a browser. Node.js is a framework for running JavaScript independently of a browser context. My point is this will _never_ be able to run in node.js, unless you are using something like [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) to emulate a browser.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: Okay I will edit the tag, would u mind check the question as well?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: what about using Electron?

Comment: Running on node js? Do you know angular or react? Building this by hand with jquery is gonna be pretty rough and since you have to use node leaning on a more powerful toolkit than jQuery would probably be a good idea

Comment: @Callat: I know react and I have plan to use that with Electron. Thanks for the tip.